# Header changes as you scroll down (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

TechCrunch recently redesigned their site and they have a sweet header that minifies into a thinner version of their branding as you scroll down.

You can see what I mean here: http://techcrunch.com/

How would I go about creating something like this? Is there a tutorial anywhere and if not, can one you kind souls give me some tips on where to start? :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's not too hard, it's just a simple [`.scroll()`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event.  <strike>I can't seem to do it in fiddle because of the way the panels are positioned</strike> **Check EDIT!**.  But basically what you have is  have a `div` on the top that is `position: absolute` so it's always on top, then use `.scroll()`

```
$("body").scroll( function() {
    var top = $(this).scrollTop();
    // if statement to do changes
});
```

The [`scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) method is used to determine how much the `body` has scrolled.

And depending on where you would like to change your header div, you can have your `if` statement do many things.  In the case of the example you provided, it would be something like

```
if ( top > 147 )
    // add the TechCrunch div inside the header
else
    // hide the TechCrunch div so that space is transparent and you can see the banner
```

**EDIT**

Yay!  I was able to make [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KEjfe/) to demonstrate the example!  :)

Good luck!

Comment: Hey you're awesome, thanks so much! I'll try to use your example as a starting point for what I'm trying to do. :)

Comment: Use $(window).scroll() instead of $('body').scroll().

Answer (score 4):

Old question but I recently ran into this problem and the accepted solution on here wouldnt work because the height of my div's weren't fixed, so in short here is the solution I came across.

**JSfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Lighty_46/27f4k/12/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var bluebutton = $('#blue_link').offset().top - parseFloat($('#blue_link').css('marginBottom').replace(/auto/, 0));

var bluebuttonbottom = $('#blue_block_bottom').offset().top - $('#main_nav').height() - parseFloat($('#blue_link').css('marginBottom').replace(/auto/, 0));

$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    // what the y position of the scroll is
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    // whether that's below the top of the div
        if (y >= bluebutton) {

    // if so, ad the fixed class
        $('.home_nav').addClass('blue_selected');

}

    // whether you have passed the bottom of the div
        if (y >= bluebuttonbottom) {

    // if so remove the selected class
        $('.home_nav').removeClass('blue_selected');

        } else {

    // otherwise remove it
        $('.home_nav').removeClass('blue_selected');
}

});
});
```

SO basically,

- **$('#blue_link')** was the top div I wanted to to trigger the class change
- **$('#blue_block_bottom')** was the div I wanted to to trigger the class removal
- **$('#main_nav')** was my fixed header

So when the bottom of my header reaches the top of the div, the class "blue_selected" is applied to ".home_nav" ..... then if the bottom of the div passes the bottom of the header the class "blue_selected" is removed from ".home_nav".

**You will need to repeat this for each of your buttons with their respective div's**

I have tested it in Chrome, Firefox and IE 10 to 8 (works in 8 but the fiddle breaks slightly).

Hope this helps, it probably isn't the best way to do it in all honesty and it probably has some errors in there somewhere but it was the only one I got working.

Comment: Fiddle is 404, any chance you still have an example? I'd love to see it.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [Floating Divs](http://www.jtricks.com/javascript/navigation/floating.html)

What you are looking is for is that you need to define a Div as floating Div and then it always stays on the page whenever you scroll. In Techcrunch they are having their headers in the Center top and so it always stays there

Answer (score 2):

```
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $("#header").addClass("not-transparent");
    }
    else {
        $("#header").removeClass("not-transparent");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one idea

- Bind to `document.body.onscroll` event
- `onscroll` check for the scroll position. if is not at top, replace the image at the bar
- if it as at top, display the other image

Answer (score 0):

Although the answers before seem a perfect solution, it appears that TechCrunch use z-index and fixed positioning to make this scroll effect.

[image: Desmond on Imageshack]

As you can see from the image above, both the large and small header are both on the screen and this wouldn't happen without tweaking the jQuery scroll event.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code its work on my side

```
<script src='js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function() {

        $.mobile.fixedtoolbar.prototype.options.tapToggle = false;
        $.mobile.fixedtoolbar.prototype.options.hideDuringFocus = "";

    });
</script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
```