# Converting jquery to prototype.js for scrollTop equivalent change to header as you scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I am still a relative noob when it comes to javascript and especially going into jquery, prototype.js and such.  I am trying to duplicate something similar to the http://giglocator.com header (or, to a lesser extent, TechCrunch's redesigned header) where a portion of the header stays on screen once you scroll past a certain point.  This boils down to changing header code from relative position to fixed position once a person has scroled past xxx number of pixels.  I came across vinceh's answer at [Header changes as you scroll down (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687580/header-changes-as-you-scroll-down-jquery) which included a fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/KEjfe/ ) he created.  I managed to tweak his code up to more or less do a giglocator type header using the following script code instead:

```
$("#body").scroll( function() {
    var value = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( value > 120 )
        $("#header").css("position", "fixed").css("top", "0");
    else
        $("#header").css("position", "relative").css("top", "120px");
});
```

So that is great except that I am trying to do this with a forum software package that uses prototype.js and scriptaculous.  It seems like a waste to load jquery just for this (in addition to the others).  Is there any way to convert the code above so that it works in prototype/scriptaculous?  Or is there a way to just load jquery's scrolltop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the fiddle here is the equivalent; http://jsfiddle.net/S7gpT/1/

```
Event.observe("body", "scroll", function() {
    var value = this.scrollTop;
    if ( value > 120 )
        $("header").setStyle({border: "1px solid blue"});
    else
        $("header").setStyle({border: "1px solid green"});
});
```

It looks very similar because when it comes to DOM the two libraries are functionally similar. The differences are circumstantial...

- [`$()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar/) takes an ID instead of CSS selector so it does not need a `#` character.
- The name of an event is passed as a string to [`observe()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/observe/) instead of using a dedicated function.
- `scrollTop` is an existing property of elements, no need to wrap it in another function.
- `css()` is replaced with `setStyle()`

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you very much!  I was able to adapt this to match exactly what I wanted.